# Difference between general truth, fact and permanent situation in Present Simple

Tags: present-tense

I've been confused recently between general truth, fact and permanent situation in present simple.
 I happen to mix things up when I'm asked to tell the function of using present simple in a sentence. Can you tell me the "decisive" differences between these 3 cases? How can i decide which function is present simple used for in a sentence among these 3 analogous functions?

Examples of each:

- Earth revolves around the sun. (Fact)
- US people like fried food. (General Truth)
- I like fried food. (Permanent situation)

Comment: Where did you get these three terms from?

Comment: Yes, these are not universal terms. Example sentences and a linked reference are needed.

Comment: Here are some http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/presten1.html